# Exportar archivo - Funciona en Chrome, no en Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

estoy intentando implementar una función que almacene la información contenida en una variable en un fichero de texto (dicha información también sería texto). Encontré el siguiente código:

```
function exportarAlumnos (content, fileName, contentType) {
var a = document.createElement("a");
var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
}
```

Hago una llamada a la función:

```
    exportarAlumnos(alumnos, nombreArchivo, 'text/plain');
```

Donde: "alumnos" es una variable que contiene texto, un string, y  "nombreArchivo" es otra variable que contiene el nombre del archivo, por ejemplo, 'json.txt'.

Funciona correctamente en Chrome, pero no en Firefox, y necesitaría que fuera funcional, al menos, en ambos navegadores.

¿Sabéis a qué puede deberse?, Gracias!

Comment: Si no funciona la consola te debería de estar arrojando un error. ¿Podrías facilitarnoslo?

Comment: Buenas tardes PHPMyguel, no muestra ningún error. Sencillamente no "descarga", "exporta", el documento. Gracias por su comentario.

Answer (score 1):

tu problema es que para realizar eso en Firefox, antes debes de añadir el enlace al DOM para que este tenga el evento `click`

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: Modifico en base a su respuesta, quedando: 
function exportarAlumnos (content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}

Por desgracia sigue sin funcionar. Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código, aportado por Arngue, tampoco funciona:

```
function exportarAlumnos (content, fileName, contentType) 
{ 
  var a = document.createElement("a"); 
  var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType}); 
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file); 
  a.download = fileName; document.body.appendChild(a); a.click(); 
}
```

¿Alguna otra solución?